# Game loop appears to be breaking at the end of iterating through array. Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setattribute

Morning all,

Definitely a novice question here, this is my first real JS project - so apologies in advance for the clunky code.

The following functions are being used to show the light sequence for a "simon" game. The code seems to work fine initially, as I've tested multiple lengths of array, however on exiting the loop I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null
    at show (script.js:95)
    at showLights (script.js:83)
    at script.js:88
```

I've looked around a lot for fixes to this error, and the majority of feedback is that it's related to the DOM and a wrapper will fix. I've found that a wrapper doesn't resolve. Similarly, I can't see that it's an issue with the CSS or HTML as the functions work ok until exit.

The looping functions are copied below:

```
// iterates through simon.array then allows button press
function showLights(x) {
    if (x >= simon.array.length) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        show(x);
        allowPress();
    } else {
        show(x);
        var timer = setTimeout(function(){
        showLights(x+1);
        },500);
    } 
}   
// adds then removes flash class to light pads. 
function show(x){ 
    var display = document.getElementById("light" + simon.array[x]);
    display.setAttribute("class", "flasher");
    setTimeout(function(){
        display.setAttribute("class", "game-box");
    },500);
}
```

Apologies in advance for any errors or faux pas in posting this. I strongly suspect that I'll be kicking myself when this is fixed.

Kind Regards

Andy

Comment: You are still calling `show(x)` when x is equal or greater to the length of your array, so you are trying to access elements that don’t exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to you checking the length of an array, then trying to use an element of that array that does not exist. You are possibly also trying to set an attribute to an element that does not exist.

At a guess, this is the real cause of the issue:

```
if (x >= simon.array.length) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    show(x);
    allowPress();
```

Simply removing `show(x)` should help. The reason is you are checking for the length of `simon.array`, then later in `function show(x)` you make a request for `simon.array[x]`, but that is not going to find anything, as `x` is greater than the length of that array.

The other possible issue is in the following chunk, but could be solved a number of ways. One way is to check `x` before passing. Another is making sure the element (`display`) is not `null` before setting the attribute.

```
// adds then removes flash class to light pads. 
function show(x){ 
    var display = document.getElementById("light" + simon.array[x]);
    display.setAttribute("class", "flasher");
    setTimeout(function(){
        display.setAttribute("class", "game-box");
    },500);
}
```

My suggestion would be as follows:

```
// adds then removes flash class to light pads. 
function show(x){ 
    var display = document.getElementById("light" + simon.array[x]);
    if (display) {
        display.setAttribute("class", "flasher");
        setTimeout(function(){
            display.setAttribute("class", "game-box");
        },500);
    }
}
```

You may want to check out [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) as well as an alternative to `setAttribute`.

Something else to consider instead of using `setTimeout` would be to use a [CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations).

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much for the quick responses. Problem resolved.